# how can i align my radio button like 2 in a row in Django Template

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

```
{% for t in test%}
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" checked/>
        <span class="choice">{{t.choice}}</span>
    </label>
{% endfor %}
```

this is my code for printing n numbers of radio button and I want to format them 2 in a row but it gets difficult because we have a loop.  What should I do to display 2 radio button in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your loop in container:

```html
<div class="container">
  {% for t in test%}
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" checked/>
        <span class="choice">{{t.choice}}</span>
    </label>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

then in css

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container label {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-night-d2o1x

Comment: I prepared example https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-night-d2o1x

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to solve it by updating view and template.
In view convert `test` to a list of 2-tuples, like this:

```
test = [(a0, a1), (b0, b1), (c0, c1), ...]
```

And in template:

```
{% for t1, t2 in test %}
<span class="inline">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" checked/>
        <span class="choice">{{t1.choice}}</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" checked/>
        <span class="choice">{{t2.choice}}</span>
    </label>
</span>
 {% endfor %}
```

Update:

You can pack `test` to 2-tuple list by using the following function:

```
def pack(test):
    new_test = list(zip(test[::2], test[1::2]))
    if len(test) % 2:
        new_test.append((test[-1], None))  # pay attention to None
    return new_test
```